Send fetch request with react-native in virtual android device to local unsafe server
I need to send a fetch request from my local virtual device from Android Studio to https:192.168.1.50:443 (local reverse proxy server made with Apache that links to Django) but as it is signed with a openssl non-valid certificate I can't. One important think I need to mention is that Django's sites are visible from the browser of the device with that URL

Do you know how can I avoid this validation

I had a prototype working with http requests to Django already but I moved to https with Apache
I've seen that the reason for the error (Error) is that the SSL is unsafe as I can fetch requests to any https site but with https://self-signed.badssl.com/ also fails.
Also I have tried to install de certificate in the virtual device but I couldn't as the device's screen goes black whenever I try to install it...

After all the weekend fighting with it, I found this: React-native fetch() from https server with self-signed certificate
Even though the solution from the other question's comment is not updated, I could manage to send the https requests.
The changes I made in /android/app/src/main/java/com/<your_project_name> were:
File CustomClientFactory.java (new):


package com.reactnativeapp;

import com.facebook.react.modules.network.OkHttpClientFactory;
import com.facebook.react.modules.network.OkHttpClientFactory;
import com.facebook.react.modules.network.OkHttpClientProvider;
import com.facebook.react.modules.network.ReactCookieJarContainer;

import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import okhttp3.CipherSuite;
import okhttp3.ConnectionSpec;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.TlsVersion;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

public class CustomClientFactory implements OkHttpClientFactory {
    private static final String TAG = "OkHttpClientFactory";
    @Override
    public OkHttpClient createNewNetworkModuleClient() {
        try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                    }
                }
            };

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();



            OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).cookieJar(new ReactCookieJarContainer());
            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustAllCerts[0]);
            builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
            return okHttpClient;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}



And in File MainApplication.kt:


package com.reactnativeapp

import com.facebook.react.modules.network.OkHttpClientProvider

import android.app.Application
import com.facebook.react.PackageList
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication
import com.facebook.react.ReactHost
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.load
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactHost.getDefaultReactHost
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactNativeHost
import com.facebook.react.flipper.ReactNativeFlipper
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader

class MainApplication : Application(), ReactApplication {

  override val reactNativeHost: ReactNativeHost =
      object : DefaultReactNativeHost(this) {
        override fun getPackages(): List<ReactPackage> =
            PackageList(this).packages.apply {
              // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
              // add(MyReactNativePackage())
            }

        override fun getJSMainModuleName(): String = "index"

        override fun getUseDeveloperSupport(): Boolean = BuildConfig.DEBUG

        override val isNewArchEnabled: Boolean = BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED
        override val isHermesEnabled: Boolean = BuildConfig.IS_HERMES_ENABLED
      }

  override val reactHost: ReactHost
    get() = getDefaultReactHost(this.applicationContext, reactNativeHost)

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    SoLoader.init(this, false)
    OkHttpClientProvider.setOkHttpClientFactory(CustomClientFactory())
    if (BuildConfig.IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED) {
      // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we load the native entry point for this app.
      load()
    }
    ReactNativeFlipper.initializeFlipper(this, reactNativeHost.reactInstanceManager)
  }
}



